# sap.m.ComboBox - value is cleared, but item is still selected

Tags: combobox, sapui5

I have a strange issue with ComboBox:

1. The control is located in xml fragment, inside sap.m.IconTabFilter.
2. I select a value in the combobox, then select another IconTabFilter.
3. Then I return to the previous tab, where the combobox is located.
4. The value of the combobox is cleared (I see a placeholder again), but when I open the dropdown menu of the combobox, I see that the item I have selected previously is highlighted and I can't select it again, like it's already been selected.

No function runs when switching tabs, no models are refreshed.

I tried to reproduce the issue, but my new code snippet works fine - the value is not cleared when I switch tabs.
What could it be?

Here is one of the ComboBoxes' definition:

```js
<ComboBox id="comboid" items="{path: 'modelName>/'}"  placeholder="{i18n>select}" selectionChange="onChange" customData:userProfileSetting="userId">
    <core:Item text="{modelName>ID} {modelName>VALUE}" key="{modelName>ID}"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is not working?

Comment: @Sid I've updated the post with one of the ComboBox's definition.

Comment: Code looks okay. Few questions: Have you used addDependent when adding the XML fragment? Have you set more than one model on the View that is the parent of the fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of problem was the low version of sapui5.
After upgrading from 1.28.4 to 1.28.44 (I'm limited to 1.28) it works fine.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why are you limited to 1.28? Is it older browser support or something like that?

Comment: @Sid yes, I'm limited to 1.28 - this is the version the client has on his server. And sorry for not pointing out in the question this versioning "elefant in the room".